# This not available in event of JavaScript child class

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, events, constructor

I have the following JavaScript classes, where in the `onClick` method of the `Lesson` class the `lessonObj` property is NOT defined, though the `init` method of the `Lesson` class is correctly called. How do I have to change the code, so that it works?

Thanks

```js
class Item
{
    name;

    constructor(name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Page
{
    pageObj;
    
    constructor()
    {
        this.init();
    }  

    init()
    {
        this.pageObj = new Item('John');
    }  
}

class Lesson extends Page
{
    lessonObj;
    
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }  

    onClick(event)
    {
        alert(this.pageObj.name);
        alert(this.lessonObj.name);
    }

    init()
    {
        super.init();

        this.lessonObj = new Item('Mary');
        document.addEventListener('click', event => this.onClick(event));            
    }  
}

new Lesson();
```

```html
Click somewhere
```

Comment: The esiest way is to turn your callback into an `arrow function`, which will retain the `this` context from wherever it was defined. So `$('body').on('custom-event', event => this.onCustomEvent(event) );` Also perhaps you would want to move away from jQuery if you are using this modern code anyway and turn it into `document.body.addEventListener( 'custom-event', e => this.onCustomEvent(e))`.

Comment: Try moving you `onClick` definition _before_ your `init()` one - this is because JS will add these things in order of appearance, and your init() will be called before it defines the onClick. This seems counterintuitive until you realise that `class` is just a fancy way of writing a Function that defines everything as `this.something` in order.

Comment: @anvalon how do you use these classes? Where do you instantiate them? Can you provide a full executable snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Thomas Ok, I prepared the executable snippet. How can I provide it?

Comment: @Thomas Ok, I succeded adding the snippet.

Comment: First off: on raw classes, adding properties by declaring them in the class does not work in browsers (yet). Secondly, calling `super.init()` after your code reassigns the parent classes properties to them. Usually, `super.` is the first thing you would call. When you move your super.init() to the top of your code, the result seems to match what you are looking for.

Comment: @somethinghere Moved to the top, still not working. Didn't understand about class properties. I think that is not the problem. If I move the lessonObj creation to the constructor, it works, but it should also work in any other method. Seems to be a bug, doesn't it?

Comment: Okay it's not a bug, but it has to do with how your code is being executed. It's a little hard to follow, but essentially, since your `super.init` assigns it a `lessonObj`, and it gets called by the parent class _before_ your classes own properties are added, the definition on your class object (the `class Lesson { lessonObj; }` thing, it gets reassigned as undefined. My best bet it to add a bunch of console logs everywhere, add numbers to them and then see how the execution is actually flowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this line here:

```
class Lesson extends Page
{
    lessonObj; // <<<<<<<<<
    
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }
```

That line basically adds a `this.lessonObj = undefined` to the constructor *after* the `super()` call but before any other code.

So the overall execution order is this:

```
        class Page {
 5.         pageObj;
            
 4.         constructor() {
 5.             //this.pageObj = undefined;
 6.             this.init();
            }  

11.         init() {
12.             this.pageObj = new Item('John');
            }  
        }

        class Lesson extends Page {
13.         lessonObj;
            
 2.         constructor() {
 3.             super();
13.             //this.lessonObj = undefined;
            }  

later       onClick(event) {
                alert(this.pageObj.name);
                alert(this.lessonObj.name);
            }

 7.         init() {
 8.             this.lessonObj = new Item('Mary');
 9.             document.addEventListener('click', event => this.onClick(event));
                
10.             super.init();
            }  
        }

 1.     new Lesson();
```

so that `this.lessonObj = new Item('Mary');` from `init()` is later overwritten with `this.lessonObj = undefined;` in the `constructor()`.

That's why at the time you get into your click handler, `this.lessonObj` is empty.

Here a rundown (in the correct order) of the code executed when you do `const me = new Lesson();`. I've commented out the function calls since I've inlined their content.

```js
    const me = {};
    Object.setPrototypeOf(me, Lesson.prototype);
//  Lesson.prototype.constructor.call(me);
//    Page.prototype.constructor.call(me);
      me.pageObj = undefined;
//    Lesson.prototype.init.call(me);
        me.lessonObj = new Item('Mary');
        document.addEventListener('click', event => me.onClick(event));
//      Page.prototype.init.call(me);
          me.pageObj = new Item('John');
    me.lessonObj = undefined;
```

---

> What is now the best practice to solve that?

There's not the one solution for this.

```js
class Lesson extends Page {
  lessonObj;

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.lessonObj = new Item('Mary');

    document.addEventListener('click', event => this.onClick(event));
  }

  onClick(event) {
    alert(this.pageObj.name);
    alert(this.lessonObj.name);
  }
}
```

or even this

```js
class Page {
  pageObj = new Item('John');
}

class Lesson extends Page {
  lessonObj = new Item('Mary');

  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('click', event => this.onClick(event));
  }

  onClick(event) {
    alert(this.pageObj.name);
    alert(this.lessonObj.name);
  }
}

new Lesson();
```

or if you want to keep `init()` but want to ensure that `init()` is called after all the constructors, you could use a factory function:

```js
class Item
{
    name;

    constructor(name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Page {
  static create() {
    // in here, `this` points to the current constructor()
    const instance = new this();
    instance.init();
    return instance;
  }

  pageObj;

  init() {
    this.pageObj = new Item('John');
  }
}

class Lesson extends Page {
  lessonObj;

  onClick(event) {
    console.log(this.pageObj.name);
    console.log(this.lessonObj.name);
  }

  init() {
    super.init();

    this.lessonObj = new Item('Mary');
    document.addEventListener('click', event => this.onClick(event));
  }
}

const instance = Lesson.create();
console.log("instance", instance);
```

Or you could take a `fluid interface` approach, let `init()` always `return this` and write something like

```js
class Item
{
    name;

    constructor(name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Page {
  pageObj;

  init() {
    this.pageObj = new Item('John');
    return this;
  }
}

class Lesson extends Page {
  lessonObj;

  onClick(event) {
    console.log(this.pageObj.name);
    console.log(this.lessonObj.name);
  }

  init() {
    super.init();

    this.lessonObj = new Item('Mary');
    document.addEventListener('click', event => this.onClick(event));
    return this;
  }
}

const instance = new Lesson().init();
console.log("instance", instance);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis. What is now the best practice to solve that?

Comment: @anvalon can't give you a good (general) answer to that because that's basically a question of coding style. I've told you the why and how it's going wrong, but there are now a dozen ways to deal with that. First what's the purpose of these `init` functions? Why don't you put that code in the constructor? Or even inline the initialization of these properties: `lessonObj; = new Item('Mary')`.

Comment: This is a pretty good way to show flow, I had a bunch of logs but found it hard to follow so decided against it. Well done, +1

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I think you gave me the answer, maybe the best practice is to put that code in the constructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code

```
class Page {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }
    init() {} // void
}

class Lesson extends Page {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.init(); // Call the init method of the Lesson class
    }
    init() {
        let that = this;
        $('body').on('custom-event', function(event) { that.onCustomEvent(event); });
    }
    onCustomEvent(event) {
        this.doSomething(); // 'this' is now defined
    }
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, because all definitions are already applied before executing your constructor. Try something like this to see what I mean: `class A {
  
  constructor(){ this.init(); }
  init(){ console.log('a'); }
  
}

class B extends A  {
  
  constructor(){ super(); }
  init(){ console.log('b'); }
  
}

new B()` And you will see it logs 'b', because in order to execute this.init() it will first go to the B prototype, then to the A one if B doesn't declare it. `B.init()` has to call `super.init()` to execute the `A.init`.

Comment: @Shamaz saeed Sorry, I made I mistake in writing the question, the term 'this' is always defined, but its properties are not set. I'm going to correct my question. Anyway, if I change the code as you say, it works, but I have also to call the 'init' method of the Page class.

Comment: @Shamaz saeed If I call the 'init' method also in the lesson class, it is called twice and 2 event handlers are assigned.

Comment: sorry but `let that = this` is a deprecated way of solving the scope issue. You have to replace `function(event) {}` with `(event) => {}` to solve the issue correctly, like @somethinghere said.

Comment: @anvalon That's what my test case describes here, you don't need to re-call a method if it's already called in the super class. However, things that get assigned _after_ the super aren't immediately available when the super class calls it, as the constructor is still busy 'constructing' your object. I would replace it with an arrow function and call it a day.

Comment: @somethinghere I tried using the arrow function (then avoiding using that) and to move the event handler assignment before the call to super.init(), but it still does not work. I prepared a fully executable snippet, as proposed by Thomas, but I don't know how to submit it here.

Comment: It's not about where you call super.init, it's about where the callback gets added. You can add a snippet using the `<>` button when editing your question, paste your code into the JS part and execute it to see if it's working or at least showing the error you are getting.

Comment: @somethinghere Ok, got it, I moved the callback before the definition of the init method, but still not working. How can I post the snippet here?

Comment: Edit your question and use the `< >` (in a file shape) button to add a snippet to your question.

Comment: @somethinghere Ok, I did it, thanks.